# Resharper File Templates

Tags: angularjs, resharper, resharper-9.0

So I'm creating this file template. I'm using the `$SOME_VARIABLE$` which is awesome.

I'm doing this template:

```
var angular = require('angular');

angular.module('MyModule', [])
    .controller('MyController.MyModule', myController);
```

So the `MyController.MyModule` is a combination `$__$`. You can see that the only difference between `MyController` and `myController` is that the first camel case and the second is pascal case. So how do you get resharper to automatically create the pascal case for you.

Comment: not different conventions? like controller names are supposed to have camel case and function names are supposed to have pascal case, i might update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `Choose Macro` from the parameters list on the right hand side.

Scroll to the bottom and there are some lower case options.

### -- Edit --

Longer version:

1. Go into Resharper menu from menu bar
2. Tools
3. Templates Explorer
4. Click new Templates button
5. On the right hand side is parameters list.

When you create a variable that Resharper can use by surrounding a word in `$`:

```
public class $CLASSNAME$
{

}
```

It will show up a parameter on the left hand side, then there should be blue underlined text saying `Choose Macro`.

Comment: what if there is no 'choose macro' option from the parameters list on the right hand side?